# Googleなどの音声アシスタントでWakeupキーワードを受取り→判断までの仕組み

Tags: apple, amazon

もし質問の内容がサイトの色と異なる場合は然るべきサイトを教えて頂ける事を期待しています。

ホームスピーカーやスマホで、音声アシスタントを使用する際に「OK Google!」などのWakeupキーワードを発声するまでの間、どの様に待機しているのかが知りたいです。

もし常に音声を監視しているのであれば電気消費はとても大きくなるでしょう。
しかしその様な事にならず待機しています。
また違ったワードの選別などはどの様に行われているのでしょうか？

自分は音声認識の仕組みの部分がとても知りたいのですが検索が下手で上手く探すことができません。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

ご質問の件ですが音声は常に監視しています。ですのでオフにすることで、端末によってはバッテリー消費をおさえられます。低電力でそうしたことをする専門のハードウェアが存在するものと考えてください。(キーワード:Low Power Audio,SOC)

ウェイクアップワードは単にマッチしているかを端末で判別しています(インターネット接続を切ったスマホでもウェイクアップワードに応答するはずです)。大雑把に言えば音の波形を解析して、サンプルと類似してるか比較すればことたります。(キーワード:音声認識)

任意に入力された発話の解析やそれに対する応答の仕組みはより大がかりで、大抵の場合はインターネット上にあるコンピューターで行っています。音声入力に関しては古くからあり、ネットワーク無しで処理するものも多いですが、現在の様に実用化したのはディープラーニング以後となり、オンラインの計算リソースを活用したものに触れることが多いと思います。